Strange color change when clicking the vote button and holding the mouse
I upvoted a question today and saw than when clicking the upvote button, there was a strange color change to a blue color that seems to be consistent across all sites.
Example taken from Stack Overflow Meta: (I have tested, it appears on other sites too)
After voting:

While holding down the button to vote:

And here is a gif showing this clearly (it is important to note that it turns blue during the period when you click and hold. Once you release it changes to another color):

Is this intended? The color is very out of place with some sites (such as Writing or Worldbuilding).
This is on a mac laptop.

Important to note - it's when you click and hold - in that period it's blue. Once you release it turns into another color: https://i.sstatic.net/OGLiR.gif

Thanks VLAZ, that was what I was trying to describe - I tried (and failed) multiple times to add a gif, so thanks for supplying the media. Appreciate it!

It happens on Stack Overflow in dark mode as well with a paler blue; it appears to be the focus color (and can be observed by "tabbing" through the UI as well). The CSS for that color appears to be --theme-secondary-400; it strikes me as odd that this secondary theme color would be the same for all sites across the network, but maybe that's intended?

Possibly related to New Focus Styles & Updated Styling for Button Groups? Since that update is adjacent to this, and the focus/ secondary theme color is noted in that post.
